# slicing 3D plot and dynamic number of controls MATHEMATICA

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am going to have a n-dimensional function and I would like to able plot 2D planes for the rest of the variables fixed to a number. For example:

```
u = w^2  y^3 + x^5 z^4 + I z^6 + I z^2 Sin[y + x - 1]+k*Sin[w*pi]
```

I have 5 variables in here and lets assume I want to fix z w plane and plot with sliding y,z, and k. I have many issues to fix to get what I want to do,

1- As it is the code is not working. I need to figure out to update the limsL and limsR for the sliders. If I remove the doloop and the limits at least I dont get the RED error bar. I need to update those values maybe using a button to get all the data and second button to plot.

2- But even with default limits for sliders [0,1] I do not get a plot. The values are updated at the interface. Under varying variables but does not effect the u function. And actually I prefer variables stay as z,y,x etc and not to get numerical values.

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{u = 
z  Sin[\[Pi] x] + Cos[\[Pi] y] + y^6 Cos[2 \[Pi] y], vars = {x, y, z}, varlims = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, poi = {x, y},
svars = {z, r}, data = Table[RandomReal[], {20}]}, Column[{Style["Ploter", "Function"],
Row[{"Function  ", InputField[u]}, Spacer[20]], 
Row[{"Variables ", InputField[Dynamic[vars]]}], 
Row[{"Variable limits ", InputField[Dynamic[varlims]]}], 
Row[{"Plane of interest", InputField[Dynamic[poi]]}], 
Row[{"Varying variables", InputField[Dynamic[svars]]}],
Plotslices[u, vars, varlims, poi, svars, size],

Dynamic[
 countersvar = Dimensions[svars][[1]];
 limsL = ConstantArray[0, countersvar];
 limsR = ConstantArray[0, countersvar];
 Do[

  v = svars[[i]];
  posv = Position[vars, v][[1]];
  lv = varlims[[posv, 1]][[1]];
  rv = varlims[[posv, 2]][[1]];
  limsL[[i]] = lv;
  limsR[[i]] = rv;
  , {i, countersvar}];
 Grid[
  Table[With[{i = i}, {svars[[i]], 
     Slider[Dynamic[svars[[i]], {limsL[[1]], limsR[[i]]}]], 
     Dynamic[svars[[i]]]}], {i, Dimensions[svars][[1]]}]]]


}]], {size, {Small, Medium, Full}}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom,ContinuousAction -> False, Initialization :> (

Plotslices[u_, vars_, varlims_, poi_, svars_, size_] := 
 Module[{v1, v2, lv1, lv2, rv1, rv2, posv1, posv2},
  v1 = poi[[1]];
  v2 = poi[[2]];
  posv1 = Position[vars, v1][[1]];
  posv2 = Position[vars, v2][[1]];
  lv1 = varlims[[posv1, 1]][[1]];
  lv2 = varlims[[posv2, 1]][[1]];
  rv1 = varlims[[posv1, 2]][[1]];
  rv2 = varlims[[posv2, 2]][[1]];
  psl = 
   Plot3D[u, {v1, lv1, rv1}, {v2, lv2, rv2}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{v1, v2, z}, Hue[z]], 
    ImageSize -> size];
  Return[psl];];
)
 ]
```

I am sorry for the formatting . I tried to put it together crtl+K but it did not work.